# How to fix issue with group join in linq / lambda expression?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have the following Linq/Lambda expression to associate **COMMENTS** and **ATTACHMENTS** to **RECORDS** (these are the names of tables in database).

```
var comments = repositoryBase.Query<Comments>()
    .Select(x => x);

var attachments = repositoryBase.Query<Attachment>()
    .Where(x => x.DeletedFlag == false)
    .Select(x => x);

var recordItems = repositoryBase.Query<Record>()
    .Where(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentIdId && x.DeletedFlag == false);

recordItems = recordItems
    .Where(x => x.Featured == true && (x.PhaseTypeId == 2 || x.PhaseTypeId == 3));  // filtering

var recordComments = recordItems
    .GroupJoin(comments,
        itm => new { a = 1, b = itm.RecordId },
        c => new { a = c.TypeId, b = c.Id },
        (itm, c) => new { c, itm })
    .SelectMany(x => x.c.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new
    {
        Comments = (y != null) ? true : false,
        CommentsCount = x.c.Count(),
        RecordId = x.itm.RecordId,
        Featured = x.itm.Featured,
        Id = x.itm.RecordId,
        PhaseName = x.itm.PhaseType.PhaseName,
        x.itm.ProductionDate,
        x.itm.PublishedDate,
        Title = x.itm.RecordTitle,
        x.itm.UpdatedDate
    }).Distinct();
```

where TypeId and Id in `c => new { a = c.TypeId, b = c.Id }` are fields in *comments* on which the group join(left outer join) is done.

```
var recordAttachments = recordComments
    .GroupJoin(attachments,
        itm => new { a = 1, b = itm.RecordId },
        at => new { a = at.ContentType, b = at.ContentId },
        (itm, at) => new { at, itm})
    .SelectMany(x => x.at.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => new
    {
        Attachments = (y != null) ? true : false,
        AttachmentsCount = x.at.Count(),
        AttachmentTitle = y.FileName,
        AttachmentId = (y != null) ? y.AttachmentId : 0,
        TypeId = (y != null) ? y.ContentType : 0,
        ItemId = (y != null) ? y.ContentId : 0,
        Comments = x.itm.Comments,
        CommentsCount = x.itm.CommentsCount,
        Featured = x.itm.Featured,
        Id = x.itm.RecordId,
        PhaseName = x.itm.PhaseName,
        x.itm.ProductionDate,
        x.itm.PublishedDate,
        Title = x.itm.Title,
        x.itm.UpdatedDate
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But with the last lambda expression there is an issue that if there are two attachment for the same record, the record with attachment gets duplicated (not in database but in view).

As shown here

```
 "Data": [
    {
        "typeid": 1,
        "typename": "Record Scan",
        "id": 3071,
        "title": "Late Outcomes",
        "publishdate": "3/4/2013",
        "featured": true,
        "productiondate": "",
        "phasename": "Board",
        "updateddate": "4/29/2013",
        "updateddateforsorting": "2013-04-29T19:44:29.47",
        "comments": true,
        "numofcomments": 4,
        "attachment": true,
        "numofattachments": 2,
        "attachments": [
            {
                "attachmentid": 371,
                "typeid": 1,
                "id": 0,
                "title": "Cardio_David.docx",
                "name": null,
                "createddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "attachmentid": 434,
                "typeid": 1,
                "id": 0,
                "title": "blanks in password field.docx",
                "name": null,
                "createddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "typeid": 1,
        "typename": "Record Scan",
        "id": 3071,
        "title": "Late Outcomes",
        "publishdate": "3/4/2013",
        "featured": true,
        "productiondate": "",
        "phasename": "Board",
        "updateddate": "4/29/2013",
        "updateddateforsorting": "2013-04-29T19:44:29.47",
        "comments": true,
        "numofcomments": 4,
        "attachment": true,
        "numofattachments": 2,
        "attachments": [
            {
                "attachmentid": 371,
                "typeid": 1,
                "id": 0,
                "title": "Cardio_David.docx",
                "name": null,
                "createddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "attachmentid": 434,
                "typeid": 1,
                "id": 0,
                "title": "blanks in password field.docx",
                "name": null,
                "createddate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

NB- this is a sample data ignore the field names and values
 I 've editted the last code **recordAttachment** as

```
var recordAttachment= from rc in recordComments
                                        join at in attachments on rc.RecordId equals at.ContentId into ra
                                        select new { Comments = rc.Comments, CommentsCount = rc.CommentsCount Featured = rc.Featured, Id = rc.RecordId, PhaseName = rc.PhaseName, rc.ProductionDate, jac.PublishedDate, Source = jac.Source, Title = rc.Title, rc.UpdatedDate, AttachmentCount = ra.Count(), Attachments = ra, IsAttachment = (ra.Count() != null) ? true : false };
```

This returns record and associated attachments. Now i need to Map this data to a view model..

```
public class FlaggedItemModel
{
    public int typeid { get; set; }
    public string typename { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string publishdate { get; set; }     
    public bool featured { get; set; }
    public string productiondate { get; set; }
    public string phasename { get; set; }
    public string updateddate { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateddateforsorting { get; set; }
    public bool comments { get; set; }
    public int numofcomments { get; set; }
    public bool attachment { get; set; }
    public int numofattachments { get; set; }
    public IList<AttachmentModel> attachments { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this code but not working

```
var recordlist = journalArticleAttachments.Select(x => new FlaggedItemModel() {  attachments = x.Attachments.Where(z => z.ContentId == x.Id).Select(jaa => new AttachmentModel() { attachmentid = jaa.AttachmentId, typeid = jaa.ContentType, title = jaa.FileName }).ToList(), numofcomments = x.CommentsCount, comments = x.Comments, featured = x.Featured, id = x.Id, phasename = x.PhaseName, productiondate = (x.ProductionDate.HasValue) ? x.ProductionDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty, publishdate = (x.PublishedDate.HasValue) ? x.PublishedDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty, title = x.Title, typeid = 1, typename = "Journal Scan", updateddate = x.UpdatedDate.ToShortDateString(), updateddateforsorting = x.UpdatedDate });
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is there something like entity framework in the background? I think you should try to use navigation properties in stead of joining.

Comment: Yes, there is Entity Frame work.

Comment: Can you show a class model? I think using navigation properties will make this much easier!

Comment: Can you please check my modified code above?

Comment: It's more interesting to see `Comment`, `Attachment` and `Record`. Also, your code in one long line is illegible and maybe you want to explain "not working".

Comment: Not working means,I am getting a message - `Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."` on de-bugging

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29306/discussion-between-dany-and-gert-arnold)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to get the database to convert a datetime to a formatted short date string, which it doesn't know how to do.  I would recommend changing your model to have a production date be a datetime field, and formatting it appropriately in your view.  Changing the datetime to a string in the controller (or DAL) isn't the appropriate place to do it.

Alternatively, if you insist on having the shortdate in your viewmodel, have the query initally return the field as date time, then call .ToList() on the query, and then project that result into your final view so that the result will be returned from the database as datetime, and then you can have it convert it to shortdate in C#.  Something like this:

`var recordlist = journalArticleAttachments.Select(x=>new { ..., publishdate, ...}).ToList().Select(x=>new { ...,  publishdate = (publishdate==null) ? publishdate.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty, ...});`